# CSS - right align block with edge of viewport, but with a limit

Tags: html, css

I have a header bar with a coloured background and some right-aligned menu items inside. The header bar should stretch the full width of the viewport, with a minimum width to avoid shrinking to below the (fixed) width of the main body of the site. The menu items inside should remain right aligned with the main body of the site even when the header bar extends wider. So far so easy: http://jsfiddle.net/symposion/fgrGD/

```
<div class="headerBar">
  <div class="headerMenu">
    Some item
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mainContent">
</div>

.headerBar {
  margin-top:30px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  min-width:400px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

.headerMenu {
  text-align:right;
  max-width:400px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.mainContent {
  width:400px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
}
```

Where it gets complicated is that I'd *also* like the menu to move left (while still remaining right aligned to the edge of the screen) when the browser is resized smaller than the minimum width of the main site, to make best use of the remaining space. The naive way of doing this is to remove the min-width from the header bar, but this obviously means that you end up with a nasty blank gap when you scroll over to the right.

Constraints:

- I can't make the header a fixed height, it needs to expand and contract based on its content
- No JS
- Ideally I'd like to avoid lots of redundant markup in the header; I can live with a little if it's the only way.
- Needs to work in IE8+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, iOS

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried media queries?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something called a media query.

> A media query is a logical expression that is either true or false. A
>   media query is true if the media type of the media query matches the
>   media type of the device where the user agent is running (as defined
>   in the "Applies to" line), and all expressions in the media query are
>   true.

example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 765px) {
    ...styles...
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uRaMS/

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I can't quite see yet how it's going to solve the problem of aligning the text with the edge of the viewport while its containing block has a fixed width, but hopefully your jsfiddle will answer that. Sadly, jsfiddle.net is unusable at the moment :-(

Comment: Ok JSFiddle has relented (briefly). Your solution is a decent compromise (thus the upvote) but it isn't exactly what I was looking for, in that it loses the right alignment for the smaller viewport sizes. Ideally I was hoping to keep the text right-aligned to the edge of the viewport whilst still having the containing header block extending out to the full defined width of the site (400px in the example)...

Comment: is that what you mean? I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. http://jsbin.com/uguyat/1/edit

Comment: Not quite, no. mainContent and headerBar should still be 400px wide even when the viewport is smaller than 400px, it's just that the text within wants to track the right hand edge of the viewport. Essentially I have a fixed width site, but I want the top menu to be fluid - it's the mixture of the two that seems to make this hard!